# Non-Identity key not showing on create/edit pages under MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, key

I'm creating a web site under MVC4, using a data-first approach.  A couple of the tables have non-standard keys: BusRouteCode for one, and BusStopNumber for another ... because these are not identity keys (autonumbers) and must be entered by the user

I have added [Key] before each of these, so Entity Framework will recognize them when generating the CRUD views.  However, it isn't generating an input field for them on Create or Edit, nor a display field for List and Details.

I added [ScaffoldColumn(true)] before the key field as well, but it still won't create the input fields for them.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from manually adding the input fields for these properties?

Answer (score 0):

1) You should mark any column that is generated for some other resource as `Computed`:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

2) If the `Scaffolding` feature from the MVC is not generating the field, do it manualy, just put the field in the view!